# how to evaluate this limit? $ \lim_{a \to0} a \ln(a) - a $

Tags: calculus, limits

I was trying to evaluate the limit $$ \lim_{a \to 0} a\ln(a) - a $$ which is a $[0 \times \infty ]$ type...I couldn't find a way to go from this form to a form which is calculable...

any hints?

Comment: use L'Hospital to calculate this limit

Comment: The term $\ln a$ is only defined for $a>0$, so you should take the limit from the right. Also, it is sufficient to show that $a\ln a\to 0$ as $a\to0^+$. Can you do that? Finally, what have you tried?

Comment: Can you do an arabesque to create a fraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Write $$\lim_{a\to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln a - 1}{\frac{1}{a}}$$

and use [L'Hospital](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html).

Answer (score 5):

Since obviously $\lim_{a\to0}a=0$, you just need to compute
$$
\lim_{a\to0}a\ln a=\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\ln a}{1/a}=\dots
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{a\to0}(a\ln a - a)=\dots-0=0
$$
Fill in the dots.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

As mickep noted in the comments, we only need to consider the behavior of the function as $a \to 0^+$, since $\ln$ is undefined for nonpositive numbers.  Set $b = \frac{1}{a}$.  Then,
$$\lim_{a\to0} a\ln a - a = \lim_{b\to+\infty} \frac{1}{b}\ln\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{b}$$

Can you take it from here?